# What does Nikon D300S offers over Nikon D7000?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d7000, pricing, marketing, nikon-d300s

What extra features Nikon D300S offers over Nikon D7000? Or Why is Nikon D300S is more expensive than D7000?

Comment: I hate to say it, but this question and the single answer provided exemplify the kind of discussions we wish to avoid. It boils down to a debate, and it beggs for poor quality answers like the one provided. I'm closing this as off-topic. If you do need hardware comparisons, there are much better sites with rich information, like DPReview.com.

Comment: I'd say this is less an argumentative issue and more a *severe lack* of searching Google.

Comment: It is genuine question on my part. And I don't think it to be off topic or leading to any arguments. When I compared the specs D7000 appeared to have more features than D300S, So the question is what is that this camera has which the less expensive one does not. Really felt bad by the response for the first question I posted, I better use Quora as my question answer forum than this one. Thank you.

Comment: I honestly don't think this is very subjective at all -- there's a specific set of features that the D300S has over the D7000, and there's a pretty good reason why it costs more. It's okay to duplicate information here that can be found elsewhere.

Comment: @Sujit: in general, "what does this camera have that this other camera doesn't" are questions best answered by looking at review and camera comparison sites. I think you'd get a better response if you include what you put in the added comment — that you _have_ compared the specs. That really makes it a different sort of question.

Comment: @Sujit: you can edit your own question — and, in fact, that's the way to "save" downvoted questions. That doesn't necessarily mean it was bad in the first place, just, y'know _misunderstood_. Anyway, I only speak for myself, but put some of your background information into the question itself, and I'll happily vote it up.

Answer (score 1):

There is a full comparison here [DP review](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/nikond7000/)